# CK metrics from C# project with Ndepend

Tags: metrics, code-metrics, ndepend

I have project for school. Now I need to make from it report of all metrics CK (Chidamber Kemerer metrics). The report has to be like table of all those metrics. Question is how to make it from Ndepend this report which it generates it is not what I am looking for.

Please help and say how to do it... maybe some tips, documents or something this is very important...

Comment: Many tools support many metrics, almost none support metrics as defined in original papers...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if we are talking of [these Chidamber Kemerer metrics](http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-ck.html), the [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) ability to write [Code Queries and Rules over LINQ queries (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) will answer all your needs. For example:

**WMC** Weighted Methods Per Class

```
warnif count > 0 
from t in Application.Types
let methods = t.Methods
   .Where(m => !m.IsPropertyGetter && 
               !m.IsPropertySetter &&
               !m.IsConstructor)
where methods.Count() > 20
orderby methods.Count() descending
select new { t, methods }
```

**DIT** Depth of Inheritance Tree

```
warnif count > 0 
from t in JustMyCode.Types 
where t.IsClass
let baseClasses = t.BaseClasses.ExceptThirdParty()
where baseClasses.Count() >= 5
select new { t, baseClasses, 
                // The metric value DepthOfInheritance takes account
                // of third-party base classes
                t.DepthOfInheritance 
}
```

**NOC** Number of Children

```
from t in Types 
where t.IsClass
let childClasses = t.DerivedTypes
where childClasses.Count() > 0
orderby childClasses.Count() descending 
select new { t, childClasses }
```

**CBO** Coupling between Object Classes

```
from t in Application.Types 
let typesUsed = t.TypesUsed.ExceptThirdParty()
orderby typesUsed.Count() descending 
select new { t, typesUsed }
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Does NDepend have a direct way in CQL to measure [RFC](http://staff.unak.is/andy/StaticAnalysis0809/metrics/rfc.html) (RFT)? Or do we have to write a CQL query for recursive counting invoked methods in used classes (types) our-self? If so, how does it look like?